# GWT: TabPanelLayoutPanel hide or show Tabbaritems

Tags: gwt, gwt2

Is there any way to hide/show TabBar items in TablayoutPanel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

setVisible will just set the style attribute  ***display***  to  ***none*** . So you can create your own API like this,

```
 public void hideTabItem ( Widget tabItem, boolean hideFl )
 {
     hideTabItem ( tabItem.getElement(), hideFl );
                        OR
     tabItem.setVisible ( hideFl );
 }

private static native void hideTabItem (Element elem, boolean visible) 
/*-{
     elem.style.display = visible ? '' : 'none';
     elem.setAttribute('aria-hidden', String(!visible));
 }-*/;
```

**NOTE:** To know more about aria-hidden property visit the link [Aria-Hidden-Property](http://www.paciellogroup.com/blog/2012/05/html5-accessibility-chops-hidden-and-aria-hidden/)

Comment: "aria-hidden" this property is new to me, can you just tell me what exactly it does, i did google but not much understanded

Comment: Aria information on GWT - https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideA11y